# c++ multi-threading deferred launch

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wonder in which case `std::launch::deferred` is required.

As far as i know, the purpose of multi-threading is that another thread would take care of something or calculation in the background and return a value when the task is finished. It should start off as soon as the thread is created. With that being said, why do we need this type of deferred launch?

Comment: Generally, lazy evaluation is a kind of optimization that avoids doing work that is not needed. Apparently, this mechanism allows a task to be "primed", but it only processes the work if the result is actually being waited on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sub>With that being said, why do we need this type of deferred launch?</sub>

This question is similar to asking why `&&` and `||` operators have short-circuiting behavior. The short-circuiting behavior will cause the RHS of the expression in the test to go unevaluated if the result of the operation is determined by the LHS. Short-circuiting behavior could be expressed by using multiple `if` statements instead. So the language offers more than one way to express the same idea.

Similarly, the software component may be more clearly expressed by showing all the tasks involved, even if not all the tasks are actually performed because component completed its job without requiring the other tasks. Certainly, the software could be written differently by just not expressing the tasks until they actually need to run.

As an example, the code may initialize an array of tasks, and iterate over them with a loop. However, an early `break` from the loop will avoid executing the remaining tasks.

Comment: like the example at the end!

Comment: You can also use deferred tasks as a callback interface. The user registering a callback passes in a `future`. The framework does a `wait` on the future to trigger the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could use deferred launching when you only *may* need the result of an operation. For instance, you could do the following, and the future will be evaluated iff `get()` or `wait()` is called.

```
int SomeFunction()
{
    // ....
    std::future<int> futLazy = std::async( std::launch::deferred, []{ return SomeComplexOperation(); });
    if( GetSomeCondition() )
    {
        // Do something involving futLazy.get()
    }

    return 1;
}
```

In this example, `SomeComplexOperation()` will only be called if `GetSomeCondition()` returns `true`. So this is just a method of queuing operations to be evaluated if and only if required.

Comment: but the thing is under what circumstance it is required to do so. there must be some real-life example

Comment: suppose that if you NEED the results they will save you 1 Million Dollars (or whatever other resource you are managing (CPU time, Disk space, Network Bandwidth, etc.)  But it will cost you one hundred thousand dollars to get the results.    Suppose you only NEED the results once a month.  Do you get it once a day?  Nope.  You set things up so that when you need it you can spend the $100K to save $1M, but when you don't need it it costs you (almost nothing).   That's what this mechanism is for.  If getting the results is cheap, don't bother, just do it.

Comment: @DaleWilson i dont think the example is making sense to me, coz we could have used some if-condition statement to check whether launching a thread is required instead of using deferred launch.. just my thoughts.

Comment: But you don't have to launch it.  You just ask for the answer.   [You don't necessarily know everything you need to know to launch it at the point where you discover you need the answer.]   Bottom line, if you don't need it, don't worry about it.  When someday you discover you do need it, you'll know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch a program from multithreaded to single threaded with a flag for debugging purposes.

```
//const auto launchPolicy = std::launch::async;
const auto launchPolicy = std::launch::deferred;
void doThings(){
    auto fut = async(launchPolicy, []{ thing1(); });
    thing2();
    fut.wait();
}
```

Without the `const` you can even change the behavior at runtime. It is not perfect though, single threaded mode can cause a deadlock.

Comment: in this case, it could be of use. @nwp